# Loading main interface programmatically?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, storyboard

There is default main interface setting in Xcode-

[image]

How can I change the default main interface  storyboard programmatically for mac OS X app?

Comment: See my answer hope it will help you.

Comment: I can't see your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer: You don't. This is set in your app bundle's Info.plist, which can't be modified at runtime (well, it can, if you have write permissions, but then you'd need to re-launch under those settings anyway).

What you *could* do is use the (deleted) answers before mine that suggested loading *additional* storyboards at launch time (see `NSApplicationDelegate` protocol vs. `UIApplicationDelegate` for Mac).

Comment: Yes. I gave up the idea of replacing this main interface programatically.

Answer (score 1):

"you can't" is not really correct.  You can remove the plist entry and do your own UI setup in your app delegate - these don't have to be from storyboards.